# Issue on image size, while adding it programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview, margins, android-image

I have a little (& bit tricky) problem and could not solve from many hours by myself. The problem scenario is:

I'm adding **TextView** s (i.e. Titles) and related (click-able) **ImageView** s programmatically (from database). The margin between them is already very large (I have not added any margin or padding betwwen them). I want to set margin to only 1dp. But I can't.

I used the following code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

//No params and margins used for it
TextView tvTitle = new TextView(this); // getting from json (dynamically)
tvTitle.setTextSize(17) ;
tvTitle.setText(title) ;
linearLayout.addView(tvTitle) ;

ImageView image = new ImageView(this) ;
// here getting the image from url

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) ;
params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0) ;
image.setLayoutParams( params );
linearLayout.addView(image) ;
```

As here topMargin and bottomMargin are 0 but when app runs; there is almost 20dp margins above and below the images.

When I increase the margin from 20dp i.e. When I replace any 0 to 30 or 40 then margin increases but when I decrease it up to 5 or 1 or 0 then it does not decrease. It remains near about 20 dp. Anyone having idea about it...

Comment: Why don't you want to prepare you layout as xml and use it via LayoutInflater in your code?

Comment: Can you check with tvtitle Textview margins or set it explicitly that may creating problem?

Comment: hello boss check the image properties like height and width

Comment: @RupaliG... yeah I have used but cant get the problem solution. Actually (I think) it is due to some specified height buy android OS. When I decrease the height of image the space above and below it also decreases

Comment: @user527759... I've not tried it ever. Does this method adds "n" number of views to LinearLayout programmatically??

Comment: Can you check - Set all margins to zero for LinearLayout using LayoutParams ?

Comment: @sri... I set them as WRAP_CONTENT in LayoutParams

Comment: @RupaliG...Yeah I will but the problem is "margin is in between LinearLayout's children i.e. TextView and ImageView" originally above and below of image view

Comment: thatswhy below of the imageview no other control is there then it may be the top margin of linearlayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the viewbounds on the `ImageView` are not getting adjusted correctly.
Try settings this on your `ImageView`:

`image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`